# Ajax in laravel 5.3 giving 404 file not found error

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.3

I am trying to send ajax request on button click.But i get 404 file not found error in Chrome Console.What i am doing wrong?Please help me.Here is my code from html file

```
 <input type="button" onclick="deleteOrder('<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>')" value="Click here">
```

Here is my Route from Web.php file

```
Route::post('/deleteOrder',['as'=>'deleteorder','uses'=>'OrderController@deleteOrders']);
```

Here is my code from Controller file

```
class OrderController extends Controller
 {
public function deleteOrders(){
    echo "testing";

}
    }
```

Here is my javascript code from Js file

```
function deleteOrder(token){
console.log('test');
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/deleteOrder',
    data:'_token = '+token,
    success:function(data){
       console.log(data)
    }
});
   }
```

I am new to Laravel and i am using laravel 5.3.I am struck in this thing.Please helo me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try this in your ajax code. in place of data =>  data: {''_token':token},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. First, create the full url:

```
<input type="button" onclick="deleteOrder('<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>', '<?php route('deleteorder') ?>')" value="Click here">
```

Then:

```
function deleteOrder(token, url){
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
            "_token": token
        }
        success:function(data){
           console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can pass token as

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

> first put

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

> above your form